# Talyor's Theorem in Nocedal's Numerical Optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization

Please kindly refer to the figure below.

I understand that (2.4) is just another formulation of Mean Value Theorem and I understand its geometrical meaning in 1-D case.

However, I do not know what (2.5) means. I referred many calculus textbooks and just found the formulation of (2.4) and (2.6).

I do not understand what (2.5) means.

Q.1 Is it obtained by differentiating (2.4)? If so, does it differentiate with respect to $t$?

Q.2 Does (2.5) have geometrical meaning which is analogous to that of (2.4)?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $g(t) = \nabla f(x + tp)$. 
Note that $g(0) = \nabla f(x)$ and $g(1) = \nabla f(x + p)$.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
\begin{equation}
g(1) = g(0) + \int_0^1 g'(t) \, dt.
\end{equation}

But the chain rule tells us that
\begin{equation}
g'(t) = \nabla^2 f(x + tp) p.
\end{equation}
It follows that
\begin{equation}
\nabla f(x+p) = \nabla f(x) + \int_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x + tp) p \, dt.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much. One following up question: Can I claim that $t$ is the step size and $p$ is the direction of the next move?

Comment: Yes. This is true.