# Optimization: Are these equivalent forms of Taylor Series expansion for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, notation, taylor-expansion, convex-optimization

I am currently using [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387303030) on optimization.

On page 14, it reads:

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously
>   differentiable and that $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have that
>   $$f(x+p) = f(x) + \nabla f(x+tp)^Tp$$ for some $t \in (0,1)$.

(Original text: [Talyor's Theorem in Nocedal's Numerical Optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955110/talyors-theorem-in-nocedals-numerical-optimization))

This form of Taylor series expansion seems to be in conflict with the vast majority of Taylor series expansion I have seen, [i.e.](http://www.zitaoliu.com/download/opt_doc/ch1.pdf),

$$f(x) = f(\bar x) + \nabla f(\bar x)^T(x-\bar x) + \mathcal{o}(\|x-\bar x\|)$$

**Are these the same Taylor series expansion? If so, how do we explain the $t \in (0,1)$ term in the first form, and the little-oh term in the second form?**

Comment: This is the remainder form. Check the wikipedia page and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted text in yellow gives the zeroth-order order Taylor series for $f$ at $x$, with a remainder term. The version you wrote is the first-order Taylor series for $f$ at $\bar x$, with the remainder term written differently (and less explicitly).

The statement in yellow is a corollary of the mean value theorem.  Let $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be the function defined by 
$$
g(s) = f(x + sp).
$$
Clearly, $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$.
By the mean value theorem, there is a number $t \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
\tag{$\clubsuit$} g'(t) = g(1) - g(0).
$$
But $g(1) = f(x + p)$ and $g(0) = f(x)$, and by the chain rule
$$
g'(t) = \nabla f(x + tp)^T p.
$$
So, equation $(\clubsuit)$ implies that
$$
f(x + p) = f(x) + \nabla f(x + tp)^T p.
$$

Comment: Hi, the text claims that this result is standard thus omitted all proofs. Do you know of a reference that provides a proof to the yellow text?

Comment: @DetectiveMooch I added a proof. The multivariable Taylor's theorem with remainder is often proved in multivariable calculus textbooks or analysis books, but I don't know a specific reference offhand.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x+p) = f(x) + \nabla f(x+tp)^Tp$$ is not the Taylor expansion. This is sort of like a Remainder result. Just like one dimensional case where we have the Mean Value Theorem $$ f(x+h)= f(x) + hf'(c)$$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $x+h.$